# AWS S3 IAM user can't access bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an IAM user called `server` that uses `s3cmd` to backup up to `S3`.

```
s3cmd sync /path/to/file-to-send.bak s3://my-bucket-name/
```

Which gives:

```
ERROR: S3 error: 403 (SignatureDoesNotMatch): The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

The same user can send email via `SES` so I know that the `access_key` and `secret_key` are correct.

I have also attached `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy to the `IAM` user and clicked on `Simulate policy`. I added all of the `Amazon S3` actions and then clicked `Run simulation`. All of the actions were allowed so it seems that `S3` thinks I should have access. The policy is:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
  {
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "s3:*",
  "Resource": "*"
  }
 ]
}
```

The only way I can get access is to use use the root accounts `access_key` and `secret_key`. I can not get any `IAM` user to be able to login.

Using `s3cmd --debug` gives:

```
DEBUG: Response: {'status': 403, 'headers': {'x-amz-bucket-region': 'eu-west-1', 'x-amz-id-2': 'XXX', 'server': 'AmazonS3', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'x-amz-request-id': 'XXX', 'date': 'Tue, 30 Aug 2016 09:10:52 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/xml'}, 'reason': 'Forbidden', 'data': '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>XXX</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>GET\n\n\n\nx-amz-date:Tue, 30 Aug 2016 09:10:53 +0000\n/XXX/</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>XXX</SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>XXX</StringToSignBytes><RequestId>490BE76ECEABF4B3</RequestId><HostId>XXX</HostId></Error>'}
DEBUG: ConnMan.put(): connection put back to pool (https://XXX.s3.amazonaws.com#1)
DEBUG: S3Error: 403 (Forbidden)
```

Where I have replaced anything sensitive looking with `XXX`.

Have I missed something in the permissions setup?

Answer (score 0):

explictly use the correct iam access key and secret key used with the s3cmd ie

```
s3cmd --access_key=75674745756 --secret_key=F6AFHDGFTFJGHGH sync /path/to/file-to-send.bak s3://my-bucket-name/
```

The error shown is for an incorrect access key and/or secret key

Comment: I hadn't thought of that as I generally use the config in `~/.s3cfg` generated from `s3cmd --configure`. Unfortunately it didn't help and I get the same issue.